# Simple method for populating an LDAP database

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, active-directory, ldap

I am integrating a couple of our systems with an LDAP server.
I have a database of user information and am looking for a convenient format/tool to use to get these users added into our LDAP database.

Additional details:

LDAP server is running on an Amazon ec2 instance
LAM is currently installed (does this have a CLI tie-in script?)
LDAP is destined to be connected to an askbot and a mediawiki instance.

Edit:
I have been told to look at ldif format, but I have not been able to find a good, concise description of what the pieces of that format mean or how to load an ldif file once I've created it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was unable to generate the correct format of ldif.
Solution wound up being simple Selenium automation to enter the users in through LAM.
Not the cleanest solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned you can use [ldif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format). Make sure you can export your user data to an ldif file.

Assuming you are using Linux you can run the `ldapadd` command line to add the content of your `ldif` file to your current LDAP server (running openLDAP). For example:

```
ldapadd -H ldap://your-ldaphost.yourdomain.com -x -D "dc=yourdomain,dc=com"
```

-f /tmp/yourldiffile.ldif -w your-password

This would be a sample for an ldif file:

```
dn: cn=John Smith,ou=people,dc=yourdomain,dc=com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: John Smith
cn: John J Smith
sn: Smith
uid: jsmith
userpassword: userpass
homephone: 555-111-2223
mail: j.smith@yourdomain.com
mail: jsmith@yourdomain.com
ou: Marketing
```

You can also accomplish the above with the `ldapmodify -a` command.